# Cannot find bids from post_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble finding my bids that are linked to specific posts via the index method. I have successfully linked my bids to posts (i.e. I have a post_id column within my bids table), but cannot seem to 'find' them. I currently get the error 'Couldn't find Bid with 'id'='

Bids controller:

```
class BidsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bid = Bid.find(params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

View:

```
<ul>
  <% @bid.each do |bid| %>
    <li>$<%= bid.price.floor %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Models (post and bid):

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bids
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'add' => 'posts#new'
  get 'posts' => 'posts#index'
  get '/posts/:id/new_bid' => 'bids#new'
  get '/posts/:id/bids' => 'bids#index'

  resources :posts
  resources :bids

end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes, you have

```
get '/posts/:id/bids' => 'bids#index'
```

Therefore, you will have a params[:id] for your controller. Then in your controller, you should use it:

```
class BidsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bids = Post.find(params[:id]).bids
  end
end
```

You might consider using [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in routes:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :bids
end
```

Then you will automatically have **posts/:post_id/bids** and you can use **parmas[:post_id]** in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Your index action should be doing used `where` to find all the bids with a particular post_id.

```
  def index
    @bid = Bid.where(post_id: params[:post_id])
  end
```

else you can find the post first and then load the bids from the post like so.

```
  def index
    @bid = Post.find(params[:post_id]).bids
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is the result of an empty string sent to `Model.find()`. You may reproduce this error in rails console ( `rails c`) with `Bid.find('')`.

By the route file you provide, you should use `:id` instead of `:post_id`. And because you want all bids that matches the post_id, this should be `@bid=Bid.where(post_id: params[:id])`